# Is there a function that is increasing, concave down but goes to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, functions

Does a function exist that has the properties:

$f'(x)>0$ (increasing) for all $x$ in the first quadrant

$f''(x)<0$ (concave down) for all $x$ in the first quadrant

the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity is infinity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, such function exists. For example take the function $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ or $f(x)=(1+x)^a$ for $0<a<1$.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered the logarithm, $\ln x$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an example is $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.